# Block Incognito mode in any browser

Tags: web-browser

Is there any way to close the Incognito window automatically as soon as it is opened on any browser?

I am currently using the Arc browser by [the Browser Company](https://thebrowser.company/) which is based on Chromium but I couldn't get a command like Chrome to disable it.

Comment: Any user can delete their browser history anytime they want (incognito mode just makes it more convenient), so explaining what you are trying to accomplish here might open door for better answers.

Answer (score 2):

you are asking wether it is possible to disable incognito mode system wide on MacOS, iOS or iPadOS? No. It is not possible. You have to do it per app/program individually.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you are doing is just changing the destination to take place, so you may put any Chrome based browser after `defaults write`:

```
defaults write company.thebrowser.Browser IncognitoModeAvailability -integer 1z
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy a computer-level profile via MDM to an enrolled device, you can block Incognito/private browsing.

For example, here's a payload for Google Chrome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IncognitoModeAvailability</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

A full list of available keys can be found [here](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates/).  Note that other browsers may have additional settings.